How to Mock a Custom Hook Used Within Another Hook in Jest?
I am trying to test a custom hook useCopySystem, which internally uses another custom hook useBackdrop. I want to mock the behavior of useBackdrop within pasteCopiedDay during its execution to prevent it from failing. The useBackdrop hook depends on the user being online, but I just want to set its value to true directly so that it returns specific values during my tests.


const createTestStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: {
      auth: authReducer,
      global: globalReducer,
      misc: miscReducer,
    },
  });

const testStore = createTestStore();

// Wrapper
const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => <Provider store={testStore}>{children}</Provider>;



describe('test copy system', () => {
  
  // Render the pasteCopiedDay hook 
  const {
    result: {
      current: { pasteCopiedDay },
    },
  } = renderHook(() => useCopySystem(), { wrapper });

// Mock the internal custom hook (must return true in order to the fn to continue 
  // This mock is not affecting pasteCopiedDay
  jest.mock('../utilities/useBackdrop', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    useBackdrop: jest.fn(() => ({
      showBackdrop: jest.fn(() => true),
    })),
  }));

  it('pasteCopiedDay', async () => {
    await pasteCopiedDay('day3Id', mockedCopyDayType);
    })




A quick try is move the jest.mock() to module scope. Besides, you need to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Mock the useBackdrop before importing the useCopySystem, so that when useCopySystem is imported, it uses the mocked version of useBackdrop.
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});

// Mock useBackdrop before importing useCopySystem
jest.mock('../utilities/useBackdrop', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useBackdrop: jest.fn(() => ({
    showBackdrop: jest.fn(() => true),
  })),
}));

// Wrapper
const createTestStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: {
      auth: authReducer,
      global: globalReducer,
      misc: miscReducer,
    },
  });

const testStore = createTestStore();

const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => <Provider store={testStore}>{children}</Provider>;

describe('test copy system', () => {
  // Render the pasteCopiedDay hook
  const {
    result: {
      current: { pasteCopiedDay },
    },
  } = renderHook(() => useCopySystem(), { wrapper });

  it('pasteCopiedDay', async () => {
    await pasteCopiedDay('day3Id', mockedCopyDayType);
  });
});

